# How to export data from an Oracle database to a csv file?

Tags: database, excel, oracle, ms-access, csv

I have a job that consists in exporting data from an Oracle database in a csv file or another format readable on Excel. The data that I get are displayed on "Inform" a software developed by "Veeder-root", and I don't know how to get these data from this software. 
I have not many informations, I am new in my company and I am a noob for now in IT.

Can someone tell me the correct way to proceed?

Thank you.

Edit : I don't have access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Developer, available for free: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

tools -> database export

You can download data in csv, excel, and other formats.

Answer (score 0):

I read on the Veeder-root Website, that inform contains it own export funkionality for document formats like Word or Excel.

from [Veder-root inform website](http://www.veeder-root.de/inform.htm)

> Eine Exportfunktion erlaubt es diese Berichtdaten auch in anderen
>   Formaten wie z.B. Word oder Excel zu nutzen

Comment: The problem is that i have a very old version of Inform (I think), and I don't find this functionality..